# run-time error '9' excel VBA parsing JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing, debugging

Have a VBA script for parsing JSON that executes with no issue on my machine.  if I have my sister run the VBA script, shes getting an error and I'm not sure why.

Getting run-time error '9' "subscript out of range" when it gets to the Select Case token(p) in the Function ParseArr(key$).

If anyone can help i'd appreciate it!  let me know if you need more information

[Error location Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9OMS.png)

```
Option Explicit
Private p&, token, dic


Function ParseJSON(JSON$, Optional key$ = "obj") As Object

    p = 1
    token = Tokenize(JSON)
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If token(p) = "{" Then ParseObj key Else ParseArr key
    

    Set ParseJSON = dic
End Function
Function ParseObj(key$)


    Do: p = p + 1
    
        Select Case token(p)
            Case "]"
            Case "[":  ParseArr key
            Case "{":  ParseObj key
            Case "{"
                       If token(p + 1) = "}" Then
                           p = p + 1
                           dic.Add key, "null"
                       Else
                           ParseObj key
                       End If
                
            Case "}":  key = ReducePath(key): Exit Do
            Case ":":  key = key & "." & token(p - 1)
            Case ",":  key = ReducePath(key)
            Case Else:
                If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then
                    If dic.Exists(key) Then
                        dic.Item(key) = token(p)
                    Else
                        dic.Add key, token(p)
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
    Loop
    
    
End Function
Function ParseArr(key$)

    Dim e&
    Do: p = p + 1
        Select Case token(p)
            Case "}"
            Case "{":  ParseObj key & ArrayID(e)
            Case "[":  ParseArr key
            Case "]":  Exit Do
            Case ":":  key = key & ArrayID(e)
            Case ",":  e = e + 1
            Case Else:
                If Not dic.Exists(key & ArrayID(e)) Then
                    dic.Add key & ArrayID(e), token(p)
                End If
        End Select
    Loop
    
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Do loop you have no condition what tells: Stop looping!

This you can solve by adding:

```
Do While p < Len(Token)
```

you should also start at p = 0 as you increase p immidiately.

Now there is a lot more "not correct" in your code but please ask new questions as you go. Good luck with learning VBA, you are on the right track by trying, asking and debugging!